# OCZ Colossus 120GB SSD - Only 60GB seen when installing windows

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I know there are basically 2 60gb flash drives in there, is one of them bad?

Comment: +1 for the awesome product name. Reminds me of Shadow of the Colossus, of course.

Comment: Is calling 120GB a "Colossus" a bit short-sighted? What happens when we get 1TB SSDs? Or, y'know, something that wouldn't make a HDD laugh.

Comment: @Phoshi - that is what the word super is for!... 1TB = Super Colossus... then you have words with "X" in... 2TB = Xtreme Colossus... and finally you can mix-match... 3TB= Xtreme Super Colossus!

Comment: ...I want an Xtreme Super Colossus ANYTHING. Why doesn't this exist yet! :(

Comment: @Phoshi +1... Give it time!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, have a look at Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Computer Management, Storage, Disk Management (in XP at least)
This should list your drives and how they are partitioned.  It might be the case that there is some unallocated storage there.

You could also play with [EASUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/) (the home edition is free)

Comment: Disk Management shows the capacity at 59.63gb all of which is allocated...

Comment: I used EASUS once, and would never touch it again - froze during a simple partition resize into empty space.  A partition tool should be rock solid.  There's even an FAQ about the issues on their site ('connect drive to healthy pc to recover lost data'!) Use gparted

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the drive in another computer. Not sure if its possible for a whole 60GB flash drive to corrupt with the other half working, but a format would be the first thing I would try. Make sure to format as NTFS, not FAT 32.

Comment: I don't think that FAT32 is likely the cause of the problem, but plugging the drive in a different machine is a good suggestion.

Comment: I didnt think it was the cause, I just wanted to mention it as not everyone understands the difference and which one is better.

Comment: Reformatting is a good idea, and formatting as NTFS is a much better idea than as FAT32 :P

Comment: I formatted when I installed windows 7 on it... only 60gb was seen.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try accessing it from another Operating System on the same computer. Try an Ubuntu live CD or something.